# Node.js app structure, "folder by features" routing

Tags: node.js, express, project-structure

I'm making a scalable REST-API, but I barely find articles on advanced node.js application structures in terms of a big application, since most of them are using simple starter projects.

I'm using the "**folder-by-feature**" structure, based on this [article](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-node-js-project-structure-tutorial/) and this [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/338610/328501).

My question: *what is the better structure of the solutions bellow*?

**1. Keep the routes in a separate folder:**

```
src
  product
    index.js
    product.spec.js
  routes
    index.js
    product.js
    user.js
  user
    index.js
    user.spec.js
```

**2. Put the route into its corresponding folder:**

```
src
  product
    index.js
    product.route.js
    product.spec.js
  user
    index.js
    user.route.js
    user.spec.js
```

Using the routes in the `index.js` files.

**Are there any better solutions?**

Any article about advanced, scalable node project structures would be appreciated!

Comment: In my opinion, the concept of "big application" is a nonsense, you should always think that your app will be "big" at the end. What is better depends on you I'm afraid.

Comment: That's true, but I wanted to highlight that it's not about some simple example project. I'm looking for someone who has previously built a similar structure, because as the project grows you can see the advantages and disadvantages of each option.

Comment: https://github.com/rahulshukla-rs/node-express-mongodb-folder-structure-with-auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is an opinion question here is mine:

My build migrates everything from `src` to `dist`. Some is compiled and some is just copied. I then run directly from the `dist` folder.

```
src
  api
    <api files/folders>
  lib
    <common lib files/folders>
  routes
    <Route files (app.use, app.get, etc.)>
  static
    <static css, images, script, etc.>
    <I do not include src code that is compiled in any way>
  ui
    <LESS, SASS, JS, etc that will be compiled, combined, packed, etc>
  views
    <ejs files>
  app.js
```

Things in `src/ui/**` get compiled and placed into `dist/static/**`.

Comment: I see you prefer using routes in a separate folder. Do you think migration is need for an API which does not contain client-side code?

Comment: I have my own API system, for rest endpoints on Node, that loads all files in the `/dist/api` folder and auto-generates all of the `app.get`, `app.post`, `app.delete`, etc commands. Everything I run is run from the `dist` folder. In fact we only deploy the `dist` folder, `node_modules` folder and `package.json` Nothing else is deployed.

Comment: Thank you, migrating to a dist folder seems like a good way for deployment.